# How to pass the values from tableview to collectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am passing values from table view to collection view controller using SwReveal view controller. when I click a cell in collection view I stored the collection view cell's index path. But when I select a table and pass a value to the index path collection view. The cell not displaying the value. It is null... here is my code

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    text=seltext;
    NSLog(@"text %@",text);

 // HERE I AM GETTING VALUES FROM TABLE VIEW CONTROLLER

    self.displayindex=Viewindex;
    NSLog(@"self dispaly %@",Viewindex);

  // HERE I AM GETTING INDEX PATH OF SELECTED COLLECTION CELL

    Cell *cells = (Cell *)[collectionData cellForItemAtIndexPath: self.displayindex];
    cells.subjectLabel.text=@"djhfkjdshfjkhd";
    cells.cellView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    NSLog(@"cell is %@",cells);
    NSLog(@"text %@",text);

// CELL IS NULL HERE AND NOTHING IS DISPLAYING EVEN IF I PASS THE CELL FRO ITEM INDEXPATH

        }




- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // we're going to use a custom UICollectionViewCell, which will hold subject and room number
    Cell *myCell = [collectionData dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TableCell"



                                                             forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ((indexPath.row == 20) ||  (indexPath.row == 21)  || ( indexPath.row == 23)  ||  ( indexPath.row == 24))
    {
        myCell.hidden=YES;
    }




   // if (indexPath.row < 20 || indexPath.row == 22  )
 if (indexPath.row < 10 || (indexPath.row >14 && indexPath.row <20) ||indexPath.row ==22)
{


    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
       NSArray *Object=  [[jsonData valueForKey:@"TimeTabledPeriods"]objectAtIndex:0];


        //myCell.roomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%ld,%ld}", (long)indexPath.section ,  (long)indexPath.row];
        myCell.roomLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Room: %@", [Object valueForKey:@"RoomDescription"]];

        myCell.subjectLabel.text =  [Object valueForKey:@"SubjectDescription"];

       // myCell.cellView.backgroundColor= [UIColor grayColor];
        [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setTag:indexPath.row];
        [myCell.LearningChoiceYellowOutlet setHidden:YES];


        [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }
   else  (indexPath.row == 1) {

        NSArray *Object=  [[jsonData valueForKey:@"TimeTabledPeriods"]objectAtIndex:3];
       NSLog(@"objectATIndex 3 %@",Object);


       //myCell.roomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{%ld,%ld}", (long)indexPath.section ,  (long)indexPath.row];
        myCell.roomLabel.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Room: %@", [Object valueForKey:@"RoomDescription"]];

        myCell.subjectLabel.text =  [Object valueForKey:@"SubjectDescription"];
        //myCell.cellView.backgroundColor= [UIColor grayColor];
        [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet setTag:indexPath.row];
       [myCell.LearningChoiceYellowOutlet setHidden:YES];
        [myCell.redXbuttonOutlet addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
      // ..... some more code here just like above
    }


-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{

        NSLog(@"tag number is = %d",[sender tag]);
        NSLog(@"Button");


//Storing index path when cancel Button is clicked
        deletindexpath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
    _appDFel.appindex=deletindexpath;

        NSLog(@" _appDFel.appindex %@", _appDFel.appindex);


        alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Delete session" message:@"Do you want to delete this session" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        alert.delegate=self;
        [alert show];

    }




- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    NSLog(@"indexpath %@",deletindexpath);
    if (deletindexpath!=nil) {

//enabling SWReveal view conttroller after cancel button is clicked        

        Cell *cells = (Cell *)[collectionData cellForItemAtIndexPath:deletindexpath];

        NSLog(@"cell %@",cells.subjectLabel.text);
        NSString *textString=cells.subjectLabel.text;
        _appDFel.TextString=textString;
        cells.subjectLabel.text=@"NOSession";
        cells.cellView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [cells.redXbuttonOutlet removeFromSuperview];
        NSLog(@"swiping is done here");
        [self fetchinfOfData];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
        //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SwipeLeftSegue" sender:nil];

           }
```

}

Comment: What have you tried to debug this? There is a lot of code here and it's not easy to diagnose by just reading it.

Comment: Can you try to explain the problem better? What is the use-case here? Why are you trying to get the Cell-object at a specific indexPath, instead of getting if from the dataSource? Do you need the cell, or just the data?  Or are you trying to update a Cell? And **what** is `Viewindex`? The selected indexPath from the `tableView`?

Answer (score 4):

On the top of my head i'd say your cell doesn't exist, you need to alloc/init it or `dequeueWithReuseIdentifier`.

Also, you're using "Cell" to create your cell, and not `UICollectionViewCell` ; this might be an issue unless you're using a custom cell called `Cell`

If this doesn't help, could you add more code to your description? The cellforrow and the data passing method(s).

Comment: Cell is an Custom Cell class

Comment: I'm not totally confident with your code. Even if it might not fix anything, i suggest you move bits of code to different classes (aka json parsing). Also, I think cells are created after the view appeared, have you tried moving your stuff from `viewWillAppear` to      `viewDidLoad`? (or somewhere similar that is 'after loading')